# Error when navigating to a page after creating stackNavigator in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am creating an app with react-native and I would like to use `createStackNavigator` to have three screens. I have a button that I would like to be used to take the user to the third screen.

Here is my code for `createStackNavigator`

```js
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
      Login: { 
        screen: LoginActivity 
      },

      Profile: { 
        screen: ProfileActivity 
      },

      MakeAccount: { 
        screen: MainProject 
      }

   });

  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

  export default AppContainer;
```

Here is my code for the button that navigate to the page/screen

```js
<Button title="Click Here To Create an Account" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MakeAccount')} color="#2196F3" />
```

When I run my app on an iso simulator with Xcode, I get the following message:

[image]

I don't know why this is happening...

Also, here's my `MainProject` class:

```js
class MainProject extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props) 

        this.state = {
            UserName: '',
            UserEmail: '',
            UserPassword: ''
        }
    }

    UserRegistrationFunction = () => {
        const { UserName } = this.state;
        const { UserEmail } = this.state;
        const { UserPassword } = this.state; 

        fetch('http://ip/user_registration.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({

                email: UserEmail,

                password: UserPassword

              })

    }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {


            Alert.alert(responseJson);   
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, color: "#000", textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 15}}>User Registron Form</Text>
            <TextInput


                placeholder="Enter User Name"
                onChangeText={UserName => this.setState({UserName})}

                  underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

                style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
                />
           <TextInput


                placeholder="Enter User Email"
                onChangeText={UserEmail => this.setState({UserEmail})}


                underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

                style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
                />

        <TextInput

                placeholder="Enter User Password"
                onChangeText={UserPassword => this.setState({UserPassword})}

                  underlineColorAndroid='transparent'

                style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}

                secureTextEntry={true}
                />

                <Button title="Click Here To Register" onPress={this.UserRegistrationFunction} color="#2196F3" />
        </View>
        );
    }   
}

export default MainProject;
```

Comment: it is a class component. class MainProject extends Component

Comment: I have added to the class code to my question

Comment: I have also import the component import MainProject from './account';

Comment: My suggestion about your question is: edit it to focus on showing the `MainProject` class, and your imports and exports, removing that part about the button, because your problem is not about button click or stack creation, it's something about Component and imports/exports, based on the error you show. With a more focused question, maybe someone else with more expertise could help us here

Comment: thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: To add on Calvin's point, it may be because your import statement (which should be in the same file as `createStackNavigator`) is not configured properly.  Note that the import path is relative to the file that it is in. - So if the path is `./account`, that means `MainProject` is in a subdirectory relative from where `createStackNavigator` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you have posted here, it seems that the creation of `stackNavigator` is ok. The error message is very clear about the problem:

> "MakeAccount" must be a React Component.

So, it probably means that you are not extending `React.Component` on `MainProject` class, or your imports/exports are not correct either where the `MainProject` are being instantiated OR where you are importing the class (That should be in the same file that you create the stack).

It needs to be something like this, on the file where you instantiate `MainProject`:

```js
import React from "react";
export default class MainProject extends React.Component {
  ...
}
```

Then import it where you are creating the navigator as:

```js
import MainProject from "./CompletePathToMainProject";
...
//Your logic of stackNavigator creation
```

I don't know how your folders and files are structured, so above `CompletePathToMainProject` means something like `./account/MainProject.js` based on the informations you gave until now